# A problem related to characters mod $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Show that for any prime $p$ and positive integer $k$ dividing $p-1,$ there is a map $\chi$  from the set $\{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$ of nonzero remainders to the set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ of complex number $z$ satisfying $z^k=1$ such that $\chi(ab) = \chi(a)\chi(b)$ and $\chi(a)=1 \in A$ precisely when $x^k \equiv a \pmod p$  has a solution.

My attempt: Let the multiplicative group $\{1,2,\cdots,p-1, *_{p}\}$ be $G$. Let the $(p-1)/k$ order cyclic subgroup be $H$. The composition of two maps: projection map from $G$ onto $G/H,$ and the trivial map from $G/H$ to the solutions of $x^k=1$ leads very close to the solution but I am not sure whether it satisfies the condition:

*$\chi(a)=1 \in A$ precisely when $x^k \equiv a \pmod p$  has a solution.*

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at $$\chi(g^n) = e^{2i\pi a n/m}$$ where $g$ is a fixed generator of $\Bbb{Z/p Z}^\times$.

For which $m$ is it well defined ?

Every character of $\Bbb{Z/p Z}^\times$ is of this form for some $a,m$.